# Need to modify yui 'key press' event handling

Tags: yui

I want to make some modification to the key.js file to be able to handle modifiers other than "shift", "alt", "ctrl", or "meta i.e. something like this  'down:50+alt+49' (altkey+onekey+towkey)should also work.

[url]http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/key.html[/url]

How can i make changes to this file and make sure the modified file is used when i call

YUI().use("event-key", function(Y) {
    Y.on('key', function() {console.log('test');
    }, '#my-input-element',  'down:50+alt+49');

Thanks in advance.
KD

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the core YUI JS (which can cause trouble down the road when updating YUI), have you considered creating a synthetic event for that specific keystroke combination?

Examples/Documentation here:

- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/synths.html
- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/synth-example.html
- http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/event-konami

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to load your modified file through a  tag right after loading yui-min.js and before calling YUI().use.   When your file is loaded, if it has the same name as the original in the YUI.add() wrapper, the loader will know the requirement for 'event-key' is fulfilled and it will not load the version from the Yahoo sites.  It will, however, fill in the dependencies it needs.